# modified queens

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, boolean-algebra, chessboard

For the formulation of a modified N queens.

Unlike the original Queens problem, there is just one rule-**all N queens must be placed row-wise first**.

The goal is to select the smallest integer $p$ such that $p^2 \geq N$.

I am thinking this boolean expression for *x_i_j*, which represents $i$-th row and $j$-th column:

```
x_1_1 & x_1_2 & ...x_1_p &
x_2_1 & x_2_2 & ...x_2_p &
... &
... &
x_p_1 & x_p_2 & ...x_p_p
```

Is the expression correctly represented? Or there will be 'or' instead of '&'. Any clue/help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth adding more info about the rule, you mention the "original Queens problem", but not everyone might be familiar with what that is in this context. Also your example is strange, you dont have any queen on last row, isnt the queens problem supposed to have a queen on each row? Again, clear statement of the problem you are trying to solve will help understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually here there is just one rule- all N queens must be placed row-wise first. So after the 17 queens are filled the last 8 boxes are left blank. I didn't list the original rules here as there are no row, column, or diagonal restrictions but just the one rule I mentioned. It might make it seem more complicated. The original rules are here: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~isil/cs389L/bdd.pdf page 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression does not seem to be correct, the way you wrote it will evaluate to boolean true only if there is queen on every position on the $p \times p$ board. What you want instead is to identify a location of last queen so that $N$ queens are placed, say it will be on position $i,j$ (we must have $(i-1)p+j=N$). Then we want all $x_{a,b}$ with $a \leq i$ or $a=i$ and $b \leq j$ to evaluate to true. The rest of the positions will have no queen, so $x_{a,b}$ should evaluate to false there. If you write it in a little matrix, you want

\begin{array}{c|cc}
&1&2&\dots&j&j+1&\dots&p \\
\hline
1&true&true&\dots&true&true&\dots&true\\
2&true&true&\dots&true&true&\dots&true\\
\vdots\\
i-1&true&true&\dots&true&true&\dots&true\\
i&true&true&\dots&true&false&\dots&false\\
i+1&false&false&\dots&false&false&\dots&false\\
\vdots\\
p&false&false&\dots&false&false&\dots&false
\end{array}

So now just connect these with logical and, use logical negation where the variable needs to evaluate to false, and you should get something like this:

$$
x_{1,1} \land x_{1,2} \land \dots \land x_{1,p}\\
\land x_{2,1} \land x_{2,2} \land \dots \land x_{2,p}\\
\vdots\\
\land x_{i,1} \land x_{i,2} \land \dots \land x_{i,j} \land \lnot x_{i,j+1} \land \dots \land \lnot x_{i,p}\\
\vdots\\
\land  \lnot x_{p,1} \land \lnot x_{p,2} \land \dots \land \lnot x_{p,p}.
$$