# Boolean operator in Queen problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra, binary-operations, satisfiability

In this [paper](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eisil/cs389L/bdd.pdf), (page 28) I see the rule for [there must be a queen in each row](https://ibb.co/hZjJFqt).

My question is shouldn't it be:

```
 Xi1 & Xi2 &....XiN
```

...instead of:

```
 Xi1 or Xi2 or....XiN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text has it correct. The $X_{i1} \lor X_{i2} \lor \dots \lor X_{iN}$
means a queen will be on row $i$ and column $1$, or it will be on row $i$ and column $2$, $\dots$ or it will be on row $i$ and column $N$ (in other words, a queen will be *somewhere* on row $i$). Now you want this for all rows $i$, that is where the logical and comes in. You could write it as
$$(X_{11} \lor X_{12} \lor \dots \lor X_{1N})\tag{*}\\
\land (X_{21} \lor X_{22} \lor \dots \lor X_{2N})\\
\vdots\\
\land(X_{N1} \lor X_{N2} \lor \dots \lor X_{NN}),
$$
or you could do it more concisely (as the authors of the text did): For ***all* $i$**:
$$X_{i1} \lor X_{i2} \lor \dots \lor X_{iN},$$
which is the same as $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion for my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800108/boolean-expression-for-modified-queen ?

Comment: @svetlana I am not I understand what are you asking there, but I have modified the question's typesetting, so maybe someone will pick up that now.

Comment: @ Sil You translated the above Queen rule into an equation. I want the same for the modified Queens rule ...to be translated into an equation, please. The only rule is All N queens will be placed rows first on the chessboard and we should select the minimum sized p by p chessboard. That is all.